# jQuery / JS - Create a dynamic variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to concatenate a dynamic variable name which I Will generate from the **location.hash** and other parameters.

Trying to achieve the following

```
document.getElementById('rev_slider_16').scrollIntoView();
revapi16.revshowslide('2'); 
return false;
```

but I will get the slider/slide number like the following

```
function init_inpage_slide(){
    $('a[title*=slider]').click(function(e) {
        var slider = $(this).attr('title').split("slider");
        $(window).on("hashchange", function(e){
            var slide = location.hash.split("slide");
            console.log(slide[1], slider[1]);
            if($('#rev_slider_'+slider[1]).is(':visible')){
                document.getElementById('rev_slider_'+slider[1]).scrollIntoView(); 
                revapi16.revshowslide(slide[1]);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

the problem is here:

```
revapi16.revshowslide(slide[1]);
```

where `revapi16` is specific to the slider 16. What I need is to use something dynamic which will be generated from the function above:

```
revapi+sliderNumber.revshowslide(slide[1]);
```

Is there a way?

Comment: Where is `revapi16` defined? Is it also element `id="rev_slider_16"`?

Comment: It's a way to call the Revolution Slider APIs which is a WP plugin already installed and activated. The way to do so is `revapi[numberofslider]`. This is of course static. I basically have a menu where I want to call the single slide, into a page with multiple sliders.

Comment: so if the plugin generates a whole bunch of global variables like that try `window['revapi' +numberofslider].revshowslide(slide[1])`

Comment: Are you sure `revapi` isn't an object? Seems very strange they would produce a whole bunch of global variables like that and not make them properties of an object instead

Comment: checking now the thing

Comment: Unfortunately it's not an object. https://www.themepunch.com/faq/link-particular-slider-individual-slide/ here there are some docs about.

Comment: Ok then the idea using `window['revapi' +numberofslider]` should work

Comment: It seems not working, If you have other suggestions more than welcome! Thanks for your help meanwhile.

Comment: What does `console.log(window['revapi' +numberofslider])` show?

Comment: can you check **eval(`revapi${sliderNumber}`).revshowslide(slide[1])** 
put backticks around 'revapi${sliderNumber}'. this editor is messing the code.

Comment: something like this : https://imgur.com/a/PvwUsFs

Comment: @SabyasachiPatra would evaluate to exact same thing as `window['revapi' +numberofslider]`

Comment: @charlietfl it's working your solution! There was my mistake on a previous element check so I couldn't go through the console messages. Let's write an answer. Thanks.